# Colormap to grayscale map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, colormap

I need to export color orthophoto map to gray scale geotiff file using free tools (like qgis) any idea?

I tried qgis preview but this does not produce new geotiff file

Comment: See also http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS you could use the `r.composite` module from GRASS in the Processing toolbox.  Alternatively you could use the raster calculator to average across the bands,  emphasis a particular band over the others, or just export a single band.

You specifically mention GeoTiff, but if you have a world file, you could simply open the tiff in Photoshop or GIMP and change the mode to grey-scale and save as a new file (to retain the original), then copy the tfw file and rename to match the new grey-scale tiff.

Comment: How can I do it with command line tool so I can run a script on bunch of maps

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Shell). Also have a look [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52469/how-do-i-use-the-grass-command-line-tools-within-qgis) and [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33996/grass-gis-how-do-i-run-a-batch-bash-script).  A quick search will yield many other examples.